# docker container TCP communication in AWS ECS(EC2 launch type ), Nest js

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, nestjs, amazon-ecs

I have set up the ECS + EC2 launch type deployment and separate task definition for each container. when I communicate between the docker container via TCP communication.

set up the service discovery and get the service discovery endpoint as host for communication.

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available xxx.31.x.100:3002

```
app.connectMicroservice({
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      host: process.env.TCP_RECEIVE_HOST || 'localhost',
      port: data.TcpReceive.TCP_RECEIVE_PORT
    }   
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: > set up the service discovery and get the service discovery endpoint as host for communication.

Can you explain how did you achieve this step?

Comment: create two different task definitions using awsvpc network mode. then I have created the services and enabled service discovery (everything same VPC).
it will create the A record in the Route 53 private hosted zone.

Comment: then check your security groups, because this mostly is the problem

Comment: All TCP allowed in the Security group and using default security group for the container as well. thank you for answering @cojack

Comment: Do you use `awsvpc` task networking mode?

Comment: yes, both containers are running aws vpc network mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238426/discussion-between-kajanthan-and-cojack).